# How does SLP parser decide what should be evaluated by its cost model?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I'm working on a new pass optimization for LLVM IR and it depends on how SLP vectorizer works.

https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/llvm/lib/Transforms/Vectorize/SLPVectorizer.cpp.

I know that SLP has some steps before vectorizing the code it self. It collects candidate seeds (store instructions), it build a tree forming super nodes with these candidates from store instructions until it reaches load instructions or const values. After that, it traverses the tree using a costModel function, accumulating the vectorization cost of each super node. By the end, if cost is negative, the code is vectorized.

So I have these two toy examples:

The fist is easy vectorized:

```
a[i]   = b[i]  *c[i]   + a[i];
a[i+1] = b[i+1]*c[i+1] + a[i+1];
a[i+2] = b[i+2]*c[i+2] + a[i+2];
a[i+3] = b[i+3]*c[i+3] + a[i+3];
```

The second is not:

```
a[i]   = b[i]  *c[i]   + a[i-1];
a[i+1] = b[i+1]*c[i+1] + a[i];
a[i+2] = b[i+2]*c[i+2] + a[i+1];
a[i+3] = b[i+3]*c[i+3] + a[i+2];
```

I understand why the second code is not vectorizable but I can't understand how SLP checks it. I performed some debugging and it's not the cost model. Theses instructions don't go to tree.

Unfortunately, understanding this kind of code is still beyond my capacity and its poorly documented so I need some help from someone who knows better how LLVM's IR infrastructure works.

Thanks

Comment: I think this is too specific question and you better ask it on `llvmdev` mailing list,

Comment: You'r probably right. I just tried it here because I saw some questions like that (but not too specific, though)

Answer (score 0):

```
a[i]   = b[i]  *c[i]   + a[i-1];
a[i+1] = b[i+1]*c[i+1] + a[i];
a[i+2] = b[i+2]*c[i+2] + a[i+1];
a[i+3] = b[i+3]*c[i+3] + a[i+2];
```

it looks like there are read-after-write dependencies here, even if SLP were to vectorize this, it would probably not be profitable, it could be the cost of extracts that could be making it not profitable to vectorize. This is just my assumption so far, please correct me if I am wrong.